# How to get event target's value?

Tags: weex

In the docs, `@click` is supposed to bind the `event` object with values 'type', 'target' and 'timestamp'. However, I don't see these values at all as of writing this question.

Please have a look at this [Playground](http://dotwe.org/vue/4f960a79cb0cf85ef700a1b2be68c4e3).

I try to print the `event` object in the console, but there is only the `type` object. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

show your code, please .

the default `@click` contain 'type', 'target' and 'timestamp'. I can show them in console

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I put my code in my question, have a look: [here](http://dotwe.org/vue/4f960a79cb0cf85ef700a1b2be68c4e3)

Comment: you can log the `event`, it contains  `timestamp`,  have a look: [here](http://dotwe.org/vue/41bdec6704eb34f4beedd78c569bcddd)

Comment: Well, I don't know what happened back then, I swear I had difficulties to get the `event` object... Now, for whatever reason,  can see it in your example. Thanks anyway :)